# relation between eigenvalue of symmetric matrix and rank

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The number of nonzero eigenvalue including multiplicity of symmetric matrix is the rank of it 
can any one help me o prove it

Comment: Is your matrix real?

Comment: yes real matrix

Answer (score 0):

Let the number of eigenvalues be $k$.
Since $A$ is symmetric, it is also normal, and can be factored as $U^T D U$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$ on it's diagonal, and $U$ is unitary.

We therefore have that:
$$\operatorname{rank} A \le \min(\operatorname{rank} U, \operatorname{rank} D)= k$$
But we also know that in general $k\le \operatorname{rank} A$, Q.E.D.

Comment: you mean if A symmetric matrix then A is diagonalizable